# async/await in INotifyPropertyChanging EventHandler with cancellable EventArgs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, asynchronous, async-await

I am using WPF with the MVVM pattern.

In my model class I implement the INotifyPropertyChanging Interface with custom EventArgs which derive from PropertyChangingEventArgs. This is necessary because I want to be able to "cancel" the property setter.

This event is being handled in the ViewModel containing that model.

In the event handler I have to make a call to the database and based on the result sometimes I have to cancel the property setter via the event args.

The model look similar to the following:

```cs
public class CancellablePropertyChangingEventArgs : PropertyChangingEventArgs
{
    public bool Cancel { get; set; }
}

public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set
        {
            var args = RaisePropertyChanging();

            if(!args.Cancel)
                _myProperty = value;
        }
    }

    public CancellablePropertyChangingEventArgs RaisePropertyChanging([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var eventArgs = new CancellablePropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName);
        if(PropertyChanging != null)
        {
            PropertyChanging(this, eventArgs);
        }

        return eventArgs;
    }
}
```

The viewmodel which contains the above model and handles the PropertyChanging event and in the event handler I have a code similar to this:

```cs
private async void HandleModelPropertyChanging(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs e)
{
    var args = e as CancellablePropertyChangingEventArgs;

    if(args.PropertyName = "MyProperty")
    {
        var result = await CallToDataBaseAsync(...);
        if(result == null)
            args.Cancel = true;
    }
```

}

I know that the async void in my event handler means "Fire and Forget" and therefore the event handler continues execution at CallToDataBaseAsync instead of awaiting it and so args.Cancel will always be false.

But are there any other possible solutions I could try while not blocking the GUI-Thread?

Comment: Setter cancellation isn't a right way to go. Allow the user to input invalid data, then run validation and show errors.

Comment: Are you confusing "setter cancellation" with value validation perhaps? Cancelling the setter because of an external event (a database query) is wrong. Rejecting a new value because it failed validation against the database makes much more sense, and is supported by mechanisms like the Binding.ValidationRules, IDataErrorInfo etc

Answer (score 3):

I did go this road before - the cancellation of setter is wrong approach and it will not work as you expect it to even with the awaiting. The wpf binding that is setting this property expects you to change the property or to throw an exception as a validation mechanism. So simple cancellation by not assigning value and not firing `PropertyChanged` event will result in desynchronization of your control that is setting this property - it will show the data that was typed by user and not what actually is stored in property.

If you really want to try it anyway change your handler to return Task but remember that this is flawed solution - if you would have multiple handlers attached only the result of the last one will be awaited. With some more work you could aggregate those tasks but is is pointless anyway.